# UIButtonTypeRoundedRect as an accessoryView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, accessoryview

I have a table view and I want to put a label on the right of each cell, so in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I'm having some code like this

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.titleLabel.text = @"title";
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

However, the button is not displaying at all. Anyone know why?
I am sure that the declaration is correct, because if I replace the button declaration with

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

then the button appears, which make me think that the rounded rectangle should also appear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try checking if the button's `frame` is equal to `CGRectZero` and if so, set it to an appropriate value.